# Turn my local app public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I up some app on my machine at localhost:3000/somecontroller. Is possible to turn public to world if I try mymachineip:3000/somecontroller ? Sorry if is a dumb question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the firewall to allow access to your machine. Your router has a public IP. You can figure the public IP out, if you go to http://whatismyipaddress.com/, or so similar site.

Then you can configure your firewall to allow access to your machine. Open your router settings, and open a port to your local machine IP.
http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router

It's also a good idea to give the machine a static IP, bc the IP can change when the machine restarts.

Comment: BTW. You can't access the app with the public IP, when your behind the firewall. Then you have to use the local IP.

Answer (score 1):

Rails apps default to listen on `0.0.0.0:3000`, which really just means "listen on all interfaces, on port 3000". So yes, you should be able to access it from another machine via its IP address. (If you run a firewall or anything on your machine, though, you may need to open up the port).